# How to rename a html form elements' Id attribute using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which contains radio boxes.

```
 <input type="radio" name="categoryid" id="category420" value="420" onclick="checkCategory();" > Category1
 <input type="radio" name="categoryid" id="category1314" value="13,14" onclick="checkCategory();" >Category2
 <input type="radio" name="categoryid" id="category594" value="594" onclick="checkCategory();" >Category3
```

When the radio elements value attribute is a comma separated list (13,14) I need the elements Id attribute to change.

In the example above, when the second category is selected then "CategoryIDs=13,14" should be passed to the action page not categoryid. But for the other two categories it should pass categoryid value.

I cannot edit the action page.

**The question:** How can I change the radio buttons Id attribute in JQuery?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more. It's not at all clear what you mean. If the second radio button is selected, then those values should already be being sent.

Comment: But it will send like `categoryid=13,14` but I need to send in this format `categoryids=13,14`.

Comment: In that case you just need to change the `name` attribute of the radios.

Comment: The action page contains logic how to handle `categoryid` and how to handle `categoryids`

Comment: ... Change the name in the action page?

Comment: I can not rename because, because there are some other filters selecting upon which it will send `categoryid=13` only

Comment: Instead of renaming, why not check for the presence of a comma and act on that instead?

Comment: @Rich: In the action page i have no permission to change anything.Yes if comma is present now how can I rename `categoryid` field to `categoryids`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change the Id

Based on your requirement to have only one Id (categoryid/s) then you could change the Id using JQuery, before the form is submitted.

JSFiddle working example - http://jsfiddle.net/daTYY/

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=categoryid]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf(",") >= 0) {
            $(this).attr("id","newId");
        }
    });
});
```

### Update a hidden input

Add a hidden input named categoryids. Then use JQuery to check if categoryid contains a comma and if it does populate categoryids with the value.

JSFiddle working example - http://jsfiddle.net/KVs79/

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="categoryid" id="categoryid1" value="13,14" />Category2
<input type="radio" name="categoryid" id="categoryid2" value="404" />Category3

<input type="hidden" name="categoryids" id="categoryids" value="" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=categoryid]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf(",") >= 0) {
            $("#categoryids").val("13,14");
        }else{
            $("#categoryids").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Now on form submission it will send both `categoryid`and `categoryids`. I want only one value to be passed.

Comment: Let me know if I can help further. Did this answer your question? If so please accept my answer. Cheers.